# the packages pydub.AudioSegment in python doesn't work on window7?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python on the window7, python3 ver, jupyter(or pycharm both).

I installed the pydub package for some reasons, 
that converting *.mp3 to *.wav file at the same time 
and split to mp3 file to per 40sec files, 
and I checked it installed successfully.

"Requirement already satisfied: pydub in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.22.1)"

but when I typed like bellows,

from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3('D:\a'+'.mp3' )

it caused the error like:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
pydub ffmpeg

so I try to installed ffmpeg but it's impossible with this message:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement subprocess (from ffmpeg) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for subprocess (from ffmpeg)

so I found another way to solve it in here:

import pydub

pydub.AudioSegment.converter = "C:\path\to\ffmpeg.exe"

but another error shows up like this:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:193: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

as like many guys stuck in the same error.

I read many solutions about these, but nothing to make it better.

Anybody help me with this problem with a code in detail.

Comment: add I installed 'ffprobe' package but it couldn't change the profit solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have w8.
If i use this, i have а error.

```
AudioSegment.converter = ffmpeg_catalog+'ffmpeg.exe'
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = ffmpeg_catalog+'ffmpeg.exe'
AudioSegment.ffprobe = ffmpeg_catalog+'ffprobe.exe'
```

But when i add "C:\ffmpeg\bin" to PATH and restart os, it works.
And you must to remove lines above.